# regular expression for match special character in particular index C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write Regex for highlighting open paranthesis "{" given only when it is given in 3rd index of given string input for C# language.

**For Example**

hi{there

In below example, i have added { at 3rd position, so it "{" needs to be highlighted

As i am new to Regular Expression, i dont know how to give condition for this.

Comment: You know what you want but have you tried anything in order to achieve it before posting a question?

Comment: 1. SO is not a coding service where you deliver specs and we do your work for you. Try it yourself first, lookup how to use regular expressions in c# and try to format your own expression. 2. Its not clear at all what `3 character index` is. `{ must be highlighted ` - Its not clear at all what you want with this either and the solution depends on the platform and how the text is being displayed.

Comment: yes i tried. But could not find any examples for matching character based on its index. So i am stucked here.

Comment: yes, i have updated the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your pattern to match only if it comes at the *N*-th position, you may use positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) checking *"start of string (`^`) followed by N-1 characters (`.{N-1}`)"* condition. In your particular case it's

```
(?<=^.{2})\{
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e.%7b2%7d%29%5c%7b&i=hi%7bthere%0d%0aNo%7bwhere%0d%0aAny%7bwhere%0d%0a%7bhere&o=m)